# Quantidade de elementos que tem no mínimo o valor informado

Tags: php, array

Tenho um array que pode ter qualquer tamanho, um exemplo esse abaixo:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 40631
  [1] => 40626
  [2] => 40622
  [3] => 40633
  [4] => 59632
  [5] => 40630
  [6] => 40623
  [7] => 40627
  [8] => 40628
  [9] => 54828
  [10] => 40623
  [11] => 40630
  [12] => 42623
  [13] => 54318
)
```

Ao informar um valor qualquer, por exemplo o número 50000, deve me retornar a quantidade de valores que tem no mínimo 50000.

Nesse exemplo a função deve retornar: 3

Como esse array pode ter N tamanhos e pode receber um valor qualquer para buscar o array, qual a forma para buscar a quantidade e com a melhor perfomance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No PHP, mais vale você se preocupar com simplicidade do que com performance, visto que a linguagem em si não foi criada para ser rápida, mas sim simplificar algumas tarefas. Neste caso, basta você utilizar a função [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/array_filter):

```
$values = [
  40631,
  40626,
  40622,
  40633,
  59632,
  40630,
  40623,
  40627,
  40628,
  54828,
  40623,
  40630,
  42623,
  54318,
];

$filtered = array_filter($values, function ($value) {
  return $value >= 50000;
});

print_r($filtered);
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SoupyTenderDiscussions)</sup>

O resultado será:

```
Array
(
    [4] => 59632
    [9] => 54828
    [13] => 54318
)
```

Para obter a quantidade, basta fazer:

```
$quantidade = count($filtered);  // 3
```

Comment: Obrigado! Realmente nessa forma ficou mais simples e atendeu o que precisava.

Answer (score 0):

Como você tem que percorrer toda a array para verificar seus valores, creio que a melhor forma seja o `foreach` mesmo:

```
<?php
$array = array('40631','40626','40622','40633','59632','54828');

$conta = 0;

foreach($array as $item){
   if($item >= 50000) $conta++;
}

echo $conta; // retorna 2

?>
```

[**Teste no Ideone**](https://ideone.com/2DZM8I)